# Idiomatic way to aggregate modules into a single "facade" module

Tags: python

1. I want to combine a list of known modules (`bar`, `baz`, `qux`) from different packages into a single module that my application can access as a facade (`foo`).
2. I also want `bar`, `baz`, and `qux` to have control over what it "exports", while `foo` will have no knowledge of the contents of these modules and will simply "re-export" them.

For example:

The full contents of foo.py

```
from somepackage.bar import *
from otherpackage.baz import *
from yetanotherpackage.qux import *
```

And partial contents of bar, baz, and qux:

bar.py:

```
def bar1():
   print "bar1"

__all__ = ["bar1"]
```

baz.py:

```
def baz1():
   print "baz1"

def baz2():
   print "baz1" 

__all__ = ["baz1", "baz2"]
```

qux.py:

```
def qux1():
   print "qux1" 

__all__ = ["qux1"]
```

Now when I import foo in my application, I will have access to `foo.bar1`, `foo.baz1`, `foo.baz2`, and `foo.qux1`.  Which is what I want.

However, there is a stigma associated with using `import *`, which makes me think there is a possibility that I am overlooking some pitfalls in doing it this way.

Is my example above the idiomatic way to accomplish the two goals above?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much the only reasonable use case for `import *`, in my opinion. I think the way you've done it is fine. If you didn't have `__all__` defined in the other modules then I'd still suggest importing the names you want from each explicitly.